# AMQP Message Null when using Azure IoTHub Routing

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-java-sdk, azure-iot-sdk

I have a custom Endpoint + Route setup based on TwinChangeEvent in Azure IoT Hub.  I'm routing the events to a Service Bus Queue (tried topic also).  I'm using Java Service Bus SDK (azure-servicebus-1.1.0.jar) to pull messages off of the queue.

However, I keep getting a NullPointerException in

> com.microsoft.azure.servicebusMessageConverter on line 124
>   "brokeredMessage.setMessageId(amqpMessage.getMessageId().toString());"

The messageId property seems to be getting lost during the routing.

Any way to get around this?

I don't see anywhere in the Azure IoT Device SDK where I would need to set this once I've processed the original message from IoT Hub indicating the property changed.

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed any tutorial or sample?

Comment: Hi user1116536. Are you sure amqpMessage is not null?